# Express.js: escape symbols (POST request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Client-side:

```
$.post("test=+");
```

Server-side:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.test); // Print is empty.
});
```

How to escape it? Symbols like a "&, + etc" doesn't print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that you're attempting to post to `/test` but you're not sending a key/value pair to that url.  For example posting `/test=+` gives me a 404 even when I have a route handler at /test, because express sees the request as '/test=+' not just '/test'.

Secondly, You need to url encode it, not html encode it.  This works for me:

```
$.post('/test', 'test=%2B');
```

Here's the code I have on the express server:

```
router.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('received');
});
```

And it yields:

```
{ test: '+' }
```